# Can't connect to mysql from php run in from a shell

Tags: php, mysql, shell, mamp

I get a "Connection Refused" error when I run the following batch file:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
    mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '*******');
?>
```

where ******* is a working password.

I've tried localhost too, but I get the same problem.

I know the password is good because I am able to connect just fine using:

```
> /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql -u root -p
```

I can also connect when I run the script from a browser (but I have to change 127.0.0.1 to localhost).

I'm using MAMP v1.8 on a Mac OS Lion.

Comment: So do you have password or not?

Comment: you have double ")" at the end, and don't forget to close with ";" ...
Otherwise you better should use PDO !

Comment: Yes. I am using a password. That's not the problem.

Comment: Are you connecting to the right port, and is MySQL running on your Mac? Also, you really need to consider connecting to MySQL with the [PDO method or MySQLi functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php). The `mysql_*` functions are softly becoming deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this line instead

```
$sqlcon = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password") OR die("Could not connect to database: " . mysql_error());
```

It should show some more info about the error and if not check to make sure that in phpmyadmin(or SQLbuddy) the user has access to databases(it should because the default 'root' should. Also be sure that MAMP is set to online mode.

Also it appears that you missed a ";" at the end of line 2(the line with the connect). Also, you have )) at the end where it should be ); Add that to the end of the line and it should work.

Comment: When you fixed the )) to ); did that fix the problem or are you still getting connection refused?

Comment: Same problem. The xample above returns "Could not connect to database: Connection refused". The problem has something to do with running this command from a shell. It runs fine from a browser on apache on my computer. I just can't connect to mysql from a php shell script. It's as though MAMP has a socket layer which ties php to mysql for me. But, through a shell script, connections are refused. I get the same error when I put in a bad password. All connections are being refused for some reason from a shell.

Comment: Ah then the problem would be somewhere in MAMP or Phpmyadmin, most likely it is blocking the connection attempt for security reasons. The script is running locally correct?(as all connections are coming in through localhost or 127.0.0.1)

Comment: I found the problem! I was using the wrong version of php. The first line should have been: #!/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/bin/php. Thanks for giving me good clues. It lead me to this answer.

Comment: Ah that would certainly help haha, glad you got it fixed though! And glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'password') OR DIE(mysql_error());
```